# Zend: How to Access the DB directly in a model

Tags: php, zend-framework, models

My db details in my Zend config file are as follows:

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = bar
resources.db.params.dbname = foo
```

These are being used to set up the default db adapter whenever I use a Zend_DB_Table class, and that's fine.

Now I am writing a model class that does not extend Zend_DB_Table or any other class, and I'm going to need access to the DB object.  What's the best way to go about this?  I was thinking of instantiating it in bootstrap and putting it in registry, so that it would be available elsewhere also.  Is this good practice?

How can I instantiate it based on the config options without duplicating them in the code?  Am I doubling up on things because it is listed as a resource?  Should I just be trying to tap into the resource from within my new model class?

Thanks..!

Comment: it's not a good practice. ModelMappers are invented to avoid this -- model shouldn't where it stored -- in db, in some storage or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it into your models, I'd simply make it a property, settable in the model's constructor, eg

```
class MyModel
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Zend_Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
```

You can retrieve the db resource in your controllers using this

```
$db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
```

You'll also find the resource already registered in `Zend_Registry` as well

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
```